# Using IFormFile to Upload in ASP Core 1.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

When you upload a file using IFormFile into a C# asp core 1 application are the contents encoded (like a base64 type thing)? I cant see anything being done specifically so was wondering if the framework just handles this for us or if we need to do that...if so how.
Many thanks as usual

Comment: [FormFileModelBinderProvider](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c922b0b90dc95407e1f59510f953d220442f96a1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/FormFileModelBinderProvider.cs) + [FormFileModelBinder](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/c922b0b90dc95407e1f59510f953d220442f96a1/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/ModelBinding/Binders/FormFileModelBinder.cs) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you put `enctype="multipart/form-data"` on the form element, the browser does al the encoding/plumbing for you.

Asp.net (core) does all the decoding, so you can read it as a IFormFile

Specs: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Comment: Thanks v much. I suspected as much as it seemed to work quite nicely :)